# CASE Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to do a request in SQL. I have theses tables

[image]

I'd like to do this request but the request never send me results :

```
    Select CDR.*,
  p1.*
From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p1 On Case
      When CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CH%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I%' And
      CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE = p1.Loc_Code Then 1
      When CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CCN%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I' And
      CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p1.Post_type Then 1 Else 0 End = 1
```

I also tried

```
    Select CDR.*,
  p1.*
From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p1 On CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE = p1.Loc_Code
Where CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CH%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I%'
Union All
Select CDR.*,
  p1.*
From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p1 On CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p1.Post_type
Where CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CCN%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I'
```

But same result, the request seems to be working but does not succeed.

Thanks for your help !

UPDATE : It works now with an Union !! Thnak for your help !

Comment: You shouldn't use `CASE` when you can do the same with simple `AND`/ `OR`. However, to find out where your conditions fail, go step by step. E.g.: `select from dbo.t_cdr_appel where cdr_loc_code like 'CH%' and cdr_type like 'I%'` and see if you get any records. If so, what CDR_LOC_CODEs do you get? Do they exist in dbo.POS?

Comment: CDR_LOC_CODE exist in dbo.POS yes !

Comment: So my query returns records? And it returns CDR_LOC_CODE that match Pos.Loc_Code? Then it's strange your query does not get those matches. Would have to be a typo somewhere then.

Comment: Maybe just some whitespace that makes the values *look* like the same when they are not?

Comment: I think i have probably an error of type for the comparaison ! I have to wait tomorrow for the database to be udpated ! Will say you if it was the problem !

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `case` expression, use `AND`/`OR` instead:

```
select CDR.*,
       p1.*
from dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
inner join dbo.POS As p1
    on (CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CH%' and CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I%' And
        CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE = p1.Loc_Code)
    or (CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CCN%' and CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I' And
        CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p1.Post_type)
```

It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions in `ON` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Same result, the request seems to be working but does not succeed. maybe the request is to long for the server

Comment: Try a bit more "relaxed" conditions and see if you get at least some result. What happens if you e.g. remove the LIKE parts?

Comment: But il learned that use Or condition in an inner join is bad ,isn't it ?

Comment: Well, I don't know SQL Server that well, so I can't tell.